# switchify binding for multiple instances

Tags: jquery, selector

I am using switchify() for my toggle switches. 
I have a couple of selects in my htmls:

```
<select id="first">
<option value="on"> On </option>
<option value="off"> Off </option>
</select>

<select id="second">
<option value="on"> On </option>
<option value="off"> Off </option>
</select>

<select id="third">
<option value="on"> On </option>
<option value="off"> Off </option>
</select>
```

and I want to do something when the switches are toggled. So here is the Jquery code:

```
$('select').switchify().data('switch').bind('switch:slide', function(e,type){
// do something
});
```

but the code works only for the first select. While if I replace it with the ids seprately, it works fine:

```
$('#first').switchify().data('switch').bind('switch:slide', function(e,type){
// do something
});

$('#second').switchify().data('switch').bind('switch:slide', function(e,type){
// do something
});

$('#third').switchify().data('switch').bind('switch:slide', function(e,type){
// do something
});
```

Does anybody have any idea what is the issue of the first version (note: tag name selector or class selector both have the same effect)? Is this because of the some issue in switchify()? or am I missing something? It derived me crazy in the last couple of hours! :/

I made this example in jsfiddle to illustrate the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/yTRJh/
you can see that only the first switch toggles are recorded!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use

```
$('select').switchify().each(function() {
    $(this).data('switch').bind('switch:slide', function(e, type) {
        $('ul').append('<li>Switching ' + type);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Vt9zW/)

it is because [.data('switch')](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) returns the `data` element of the first select.

> Return the value at the named data store for the first element in the
>   jQuery collection, as set by data(name, value) or by an HTML5 data-*
>   attribute.

Comment: I put it in jsfiddle, it wont work: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWCe5/ Please forgive me if I am missing some obvious thing, I am a newbee! :D

Comment: Thanks! I missed the parenthesis :/